# How to access has_many through relationship possible in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

How can I access my related records?

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :post_categories
has_many :categories, through: :post_categories

class Categories < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :post_categories
has_many :post, through: :post_categories

class PostCategories < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :category
```

`PostCategories` table has id, posts_id, and categories_id columns.

```
id | posts_id | categories_id
1. | 2       | 3
2. | 2       | 4
```

What I want is: to get posts related to a category. like: all `Posts` `where` in `x category`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, this is an easy one.

```rb
one_or_more_categories = # Category.find... or Category.where...
posts = Post.joins(:categories).where(category: one_or_more_categories)
```

Rails is clever enough to take either a model or a query that *would* find some data and turn that into an efficient appropriate query, that might be a subquery. Trying things out in the Rails console (`bundle exec rails c`) is a good way to see the generated SQL and better understand what's going on.

(EDIT: As another answer points out, if you've already retrieved a specific Category instance then you can just reference `category.posts` and work with that relationship directly, including chaining in `.order`, `.limit` and so-on).

Another way to write it 'lower level' would be:

```rb
Post.joins(:categories).where(category: {id: one_or_more_category_ids})
```

...which is in essence what Rails will be doing under the hood when given an ActiveRecord model instance or an ActiveRecord::Relation. If you already knew the e.g. category "name", or some other indexed text column that you could search on, then you'd adjust the above accordingly:

```rb
Post.joins(:categories).where(category: {name: name_of_category})
```

The pattern of `joins` and `where` taking a Hash where the join table name is used as a key with values nested under there can be taken as deep as you like (e.g. if categories had-many subcategories) and you can find more about that in Rails Guides or appropriate web searches. The only gotcha is the tortuous singular/plural stuff, which Rails uses to try and make things more "English-y" but sometimes - as in this case - just creates an additional cognitive burden of needing to remember which parts should be singular and which plural.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers it but in ActiveRecord your `Post` will have direct access to your `Category` model and vice versa. So you could identify the category you want the posts from in a variable or an instance variable, and query `@specific_category.posts`. If you are doing this in your controller, you could even do it in `before_action` filter. If you are using it in serializers its not much different.

You could also create a scope in your `Post` model and use either active record or raw SQL to query specific parameters.

You also have an error in your `Category` model. Has many is always plural so it would be `has_many :posts, through: :post_categories`

Answer (score 0):

Get the category object and you can directly fetch the related posts. Please see the following

```
category = Category.find(id)
posts = category.posts
```

Since you have already configured the has_many_through relation, rails will fetch post records related the category.